# Private Blockchain Node Migration

Tags: private-blockchain, node-discovery, ethernodes

I had a private ethereum blockchain with 1 node running in production. I accidentally ran a `geth init genesis.json --datadir .` command in my main node.

Did this command overwrite the data directory folder of my main node? I was able to set up another node in the network on another server because `geth` process was running on a Unix system service daemon, which means that the data folder wasn't actually unlinked while the process was running.

Now I have 2 private blockchain nodes and I want to stop and reset the 1st one, but I'm not sure what will happen to the blockchain. If I stop the 1st node and then use the 2nd node as a peer to resync the first node when I restart, will the chain be corrupted? I have miners on both nodes and I'm using a clique algorithm for consensus.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions geth doesn't overwrite the directory if it was already initialized.

You should be able to test if geth overwrite data repeating the steps in a new empty directory.

Comment: What do you mean by current? I'm using `1.9.13-stable-cbc4ac26`

Comment: @JustinZ I think at least from v1.8.xx it didn't overwrite any data, but every version of geth is different and probably you should test it.